# how to diagnose/fix internet explorer 8 tabs/new windows failing to load?

Tags: internet-explorer

IE 8 on Win7 (32bit)

Internet explorer fails to load links in tabs or new windows and that ie process seems to just become defunct (they just hang around in the background "Connecting...." without any cpu or network time)

Opening IE normally works.
Opening a new tab also loads the home page fine/properly

Links within the same browser window work fine 
- except if they have a target= blank, those fail

Opening that same ("working") link in a new window or tab fails

My original assumption was a crappy add-on (containing a pop-up blocker) but the same behaviour appears when running ie with add ons disabled

I've confirmed there's no wierd extensions to IE or the shell (primarily via autoruns) and I'm fairly sure the box is virus free (no wierd behaviours, fully patched and running up to date a/v, no unaccounted for network traffic going through the router, etc)

Procmon didn't point to anything that jumped out at me.

I removed the "IE feature" and replaced it, to no avail

Any suggestions on what else to try/look at?

Comment: This would be better asked on SuperUser.com

Answer (score 0):

You could try the reset option in IE8

Tools > Internet Options > Advanced Tab > Reset button.